# Calling static method in the Widget Class

Tags: widgets, cron

I have a widget

```
class Xwidget extends WP_Widget{
function cron_addB(){}

}
```

I want to run a cron job that calls that function from outside the class

```
function xxx_cron_activation() {   ;
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'xxx_followers' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'xxx_followers');
}
}
add_action('wp', 'xxx_cron_activation');

add_action('xxx_followers',array('Xwidget',"cron_addB"));
```

Cron is being triggered but the function is not being executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$gloabl $myxclass;
$myxclass = new Xwidget();
add_action( 'xxx_followers', array(&$myxclass, "cron_addB" ) );
```

or

```
add_action('xxx_followers', "init_xclass_and_cron");
function init_xclass_and_cron() {
    $myxclass = new Xwidget();
    $myxclass->cron_addB();
}
```

Comment: that won't work; the `$myxclass` object won't be initialized inside the cron request...

Comment: How about setting `$myxclass` globally?

Comment: see update for another method

Comment: The 2nd one should work. The functions that cron executes are stored as simple strings in the db, so they should be static. The OP's code should also work if the method is really static... Another way is `add_action('xxx_followers', 'Xwidget::cron_addB');`

Comment: the second one works like charm! Thanx guys